# bot framework nlp with dispatch

Tags: nlp, botframework

I followed [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) on GitHub and was successfully able to test it using the emulator.

However, I would like to understand:

1. What is the dispatch tool doing exactly? I can see a new Luis app in my Luis.ai account when I executed the command "dispatch create -b nlp-with-dispatch.bot | msbot connect dispatch --stdin," but I need to understand what the dispatch tool does behind the scenes.

   I can see that the dispatch LUIS App contains utterance like:

   "turn dimmer off" which in Home Automation was like "turn device operation."

   I also need to understand why it is being done this way. What if we don't have the requirement of multiple LUIS models how utterances are resolved with entities.
2. Whatever is done using CLI tools like creating/importing the LUIS services and intents can also be done using luis.ai and azure portal, but is the only way to configure the Dispatch application with the CLI  or can we create it directly on luis.ai without using any command?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you imagine the NLP of your bot as a series of sieves or sifters, it's easier to understand dispatch. Dispatch is the first level of sifting. It can be trained to evaluate whether a particular utterance goes to a certain LUIS intent or to a connected QnAMaker Service. The tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) gives a better, more formal description.

2)Dispatch has to be created using the CLI.